# Magento 2 graphql image upload using file

Tags: magento2, image-upload, graphql, magento-graphql

I want to upload images using graphql using file not base64, can anyone tell me how can I implement this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Here is the solution of your answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351603/magento-2-image-upload-using-graphql-mutation

Answer (score 0):

First convert your image into base64 then use that base64 string in to graphql input.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Upload;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File;

class UploadImage implements ResolverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        File $fileDriver
    ) {
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->fileDriver = $fileDriver;
    }
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $this->uploadFile($fileData);
    }

    public function uploadFile($fileData)
    {
        $uploadedFileName = "";
        $fileName = '';
        if (isset($fileData['name'])) {
            $fileName = $fileData['name'];
        } else {
            $fileName = rand() . time();
        }
        if (isset($fileData['filecontent'])) {
            $mediaPath = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
            $originalPath = 'ModuleName/Attachments/';
            $mediaFullPath = $mediaPath . $originalPath;
            if (!file_exists($mediaFullPath)) {
                mkdir($mediaFullPath, 0775, true);
            }
            /* Check File is exist or not */
            $fullFilepath = $mediaFullPath . $fileName;
            if ($this->fileDriver->isExists($fullFilepath)) {
                $fileName = rand() . time() . $fileName;
            }
            $fileContent = base64_decode($fileData['filecontent']);
            $savedFile = fopen($mediaFullPath . $fileName, "wb");
            fwrite($savedFile, $fileContent);
            fclose($savedFile);
            $uploadedFileName = "/" . $fileName ;
        }
        return $uploadedFileName;
    }
}
```

And the VAR is :

```
$fileData is array 
$fileData['filecontent'] = base64 string of file.
$fileData['name'] = file name.
```

Comment: I want upload image using file upload not base64.

Comment: Can you please check this link    https://github.com/huykon/magento-graphql-uploader

Comment: I have already tried. In this use base64. I need to implement using file upload.

Comment: you must send with base 64 and convert it on upload/save process.

Answer (score 0):

**Using base64 is the best solution.**

**Other solution:** You can also get file data using **file_get_contents()** PHP function. And store in new file using **file_put_contents()** PHP function. This function creates an issue when data is large. When we use in graphql query then it returns only file data as a response.

Reference link :

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

https://www.faqcode4u.com/faq/411274/php-image-file-upload-and-convert-to-base64-without-saving-image

> **[I suggest going with base64 implementation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351629/82670)**